# VIM remove all matches for pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I have this textfile I'd like to edit using VIM.

```
9;Karim Benzema;France;46;77;0.6;06;;Lyon, Real Madrid
10;Filippo Inzaghi;Italy;46;81;0.57;'97-'12;Juventus, Milan
11;Zlatan Ibrahimović;Sweden;45;115;0.39;01;;Ajax, Juventus, Internazionale, Barcelona, Milan, Paris Saint-Germain
12;Didier Drogba;Ivory Coast;44;92;0.48;'03-'15;Marseille, Chelsea, Galatasaray
```

I want to remove all lines where the footballer has played at 4 clubs. (Zlatan Ibrahimović)

Right now my solution is this:

```
:%g/[^;]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$/d
```

I was hoping I could do this while using a group, like this:

```
:%g/\([^;]*,\){2}[^;]*$/d
```

Pattern not found. I think it's because it searches for the group.

EG: Ajax, Ajax, Ajax, Ajax
I understand it's not really necessary to use groups for this, but I'd still like to know how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two flaws ... the following seems to do the trick:

```
%g/\([^,;]*,\)\{3}[^,]*$/d
```